# predict() error : X does not have valid feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted with feature names warnings.warn(

Tags: python, pandas, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn import linear_model

df = pd.read_csv('https://raw.githubusercontent.com/codebasics/py/master/ML/1_linear_reg/Exercise/canada_per_capita_income.csv')


reg = linear_model.LinearRegression()
reg.fit( df[['year']], df['per capita income (US$)'] )

reg.predict(2020)
```

I am using scikit 1.0.2 version. I am new learner and exactly copied this from a video it works in video but do not work on me, What should I do?

```
X does not have valid feature names, but LinearRegression was fitted with feature names
  warnings.warn(
```

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
mask = df['year'] == 2000
aaa = reg.predict(df.loc[mask, 'year'].values.reshape(-1, 1))
print(aaa[0])
```

Output

```
24719.392589963274
```

Use an equality test and apply masking to access the value. And extract the value from aaa[0].